# reduction of higher differential equation into second order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to reduce the differential equation   $ \  y'''-3y''+3y'-y=x-4e^{x}\ $  into a second order equation ? $$ $$ I have reduced it as a system of 1st order equations  but I can't reduce it into a second order equation. Any help is appreciating.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Because the characteristic equation has three roots equal to $r=1$, let $y=e^x \,z$.

Replace and admire the simplicity of the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the General Leibniz rule

$$(fg)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k} f^{(n-k)}g^{(k)} $$

You immediately see you can write

$$y'''-3y''+3y'-y = e^x (e^{-x} y)'''.$$

Hence the substitution $z = e^{-x} y$ saves the day (as already pointed out by Claude).

Comment: can you please write the reduced form after substitution